# how to check the datatable row column value using ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

i want to check the column value of one table. want to check the column value = 1 or not.in the table row column has value of 1 but not entering in the if condition.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()=="1") // getting false
                {
                    InsertSmsDetails();

                }
```

data

```
888a1e5 1   voltage level is critical
```

Comment: `LINQ` ? `bool exists = dt.Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["columnname"].ToString() == "1");`

Comment: So this might be a stupid question, but when you pause the execution at the `if` line and inspect `dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()` what do you see?

Comment: dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()==''True" @RichardHansell. Now working thanks.if (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()=="True")

Comment: @STACK2, that means the datatype for the field was bit(bool) in database, so it will result to a string "True"(1) or "False"(0) in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list_ids = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
      where (string)dr["ColumnName"] == "1"
      select (string)dr["ColumnName"]).ToList();
foreach (var item in list_ids)
{
    InsertSmsDetails(); 
}
```

Comment: When giving a SO answer, please provide also a description and not only some code. This way people can learn from your answers and not only copy/paste your suggestion.